# How should I update the pagination links in an AJAX call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

So I've implemented AJAX pagination. The problem is that since the `<%= paginate @videos %>` code is not inside the partial that I render, the pagination links are not updated. What jQuery code should I use to update the pagination links?

Btw I tried `$(".pagination").replaceWith('escape_javascript(<%= paginate @videos %>)');;`

but i get this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

`$(".pagination").replaceWith("escape_javascript(<%= paginate @videos %>)");;` throws this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Here is the JS code the browser sees:

```
$(".pagination").replaceWith("  <nav class="pagination">
    <span class="prev">
  <a href="/profiles/45?_=1302313302990" class="prev" rel="prev">&laquo; Prev</a>
</span>

          <span class="page first">
  <a href="/profiles/45?_=1302313302990">1</a>
</span>

        <span class="page current">2</span>

          <span class="page last">
  <a href="/profiles/45?_=1302313302990&amp;page=3">3</a>
</span>

    <span class="next">
  <a href="/profiles/45?_=1302313302990&amp;page=3" class="next" rel="next">Next &raquo;</a>
</span>

  </nav>
");
```

Comment: Are the jquery examples above returned to the client with the tags (<%= %>) evaluated first?  Are they valid page numbers or whatever content it should be?  It's unclear if you are mixing server-side with client-side scripting or returning evaluated code to the client.

Comment: yea it should be evaluated first... it's in my show.js.erb file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, the new pagination links should be included in the HTML response of the ajax call. If that is not possible - presumably because the links reside elsewhere in the document, then I would suggest creating a context/link/URI/action/whatever (disclaimer: I'm not a ROR guy) which returns a JSON string, structured something like:

```
[{"data": "The HTML output"}, {"pageLinks": "pagination HTML"}]
```

and replace your ajax call with one which expects JSON as the return `dataType`. Then it should be easy, e.g.:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'theURL',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
        $('.pagination').html(json.pageLinks);
        $('#someDiv').html(json.data);
    }
});
```

Comment: ughh complicated... I'm not the best with json

Comment: Nothing to it, apparently. Take a look: http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/04/inside-ruby-on-rails-serializing-ruby-objects-with-json/

Answer (score 1):

The problem looks to be the quotes in your use of replaceWith.  You need to escape the characters of that string before trying to use it.

You have double quotes starting and ending your string argument in the replaceWith function but the string you are feeding it also has double quotes throughout that don't look to be escaped.  Every time a double quote is encountered it is terminating the string and trying to parse the rest as javascript statements and not a string.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue... could you provide an example please.

Comment: Updated the answer with more detail.

Comment: I actually show that using single quotes throws an error as well.

Comment: You need to verify that the whole string being passed to replaceWith has all special characters escaped.  In ruby it looks like you can use a function: CGI.escapeHTML(string_goes_here) to accomplish this before sending the string client side.

Comment: this isn't in a CGI script, it's in a .js.erb file

Comment: The bottom line is: can you verify you are escaping the pagination html before you try and use it in the replaceWith function?  From your code above it would fail because of the double quotes.

Comment: I actually modified my code so that I included the pagination in the partial I rendered, but thanks for your help, I gave you a vote

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I faced a simmilar problem using will_paginate gem, and I tryed a lot of complicated stuffs to update the pagination. However, I did it with a simple solution, that maybe can help someone else.

In summary, create a partial where you put the call to `will_paginate` helper inside a div, and after your ajax request, just render this partial again. For instance:

The `_pagination.html.erb`:

```
<div id="paginate">
  <%= will_paginate @results %>
<div>
```

The `your_template.js.erb` (where @results should be available):

```
$('#paginate').html('j(render "pagination.html.erb")');
```

That should be enough.